# Invalid Operation when attempting to bind framebuffer, or attach render buffer

Tags: c, opengl-es

I am attempting to create framebuffers so I can render a scene and then apply a filter to it, however I am getting an error when I try to either bind to any of the newly created framebuffers or attach the render buffer to one of them.

I created my framebuffers and renderbuffer like so:

```
GLuint frameBuffer[2];
glGenFramebuffers(2, frameBuffer);

//generate colorbuffer for normal rendering and brightness
GLuint colorBuffer[2];
glGenTextures(2, colorBuffer);


for (unsigned int i = 1; i > -1; i--)
{
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, frameBuffer[i]);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, colorBuffer[i]);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB16F, 800, 800, 0, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, NULL); //800x800 window
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);  
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    // attach texture to framebuffer
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, colorBuffer[i], 0);
}

//currently frameBuffer[0] should be bound rn
GLuint rbo;
glGenRenderbuffers(1, &rbo); 
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, rbo); 
glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8, 800, 800); //800x800 window 

glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, rbo); //attach the renderbuffer

if (glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE){
    cout << "No Framebuffer" << endl;
}
```

When I check whether the framebuffer is complete, it does not throw the error, so I assume it is complete, however

```
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, rbo);
```

Throws an invalid operation error.

Attempting to use `glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, frameBuffer[0]);` later in the program also results in an invalid operation error regardless of whether I tried to bind the renderbuffer to it.

I'm new to opengl and I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong. I think it has to do with the framebuffer generation. If you need more info don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: @ybungalobill Thanks! I just tried that, and made some progress and now it's showing as the framebuffer is not complete. Will debug that.

Comment: Converted my comment to an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `for` loop never executes, as a result `frameBuffer[0]` is never bound, contrary to your expectations.

The `i` is unsigned, therefore the condition is evaluated as `1 > 4294967295` which is always `false`. If you want to iterate over a range backwards with an unsigned variable (which is sometimes necessary), then you can achieve it through:

```
for (unsigned int i = 2; i --> 0;)
```

However I don't see a particular reason to iterate backwards in your code, so you can simply rewrite the loop as:

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
```